# Error: Undefined function 'gevrnd' for input arguments of type 'double'

Tags: matlab

I am a beginner for Matlab.
Undefined function 'gevrnd' for input arguments of type 'double'.

eps_type1_not_buy = gevrnd(0, 1, 0, num_obs, 1);
I can't figure out how to solve this at all.
My code is below.
`While using "gevrnd", the following error occurred. num_obs = 600000`

Undefined function 'gevrnd' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Comment: It looks like you've quoted two error messages, please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. Also check whether you have the Statistics and Machine Learning toolbox (using `ver stats`) which contains the `gevrnd` function

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you are using a too-low version of Matlab.
I tried your code in version 2022b and it doesn't have any problem.
[This is example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHqB8.jpg)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Fixed the error.
The problem was solved by installing statistics Tool Box.